# How to add the Project Explorer view to an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, project, rcp, explorer

Can someone tell me in detail how to implement the project explorer view in my RCP?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-27.htm but for more read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this great [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#viewtutorial_perspective) to show any view in your perspective. The rest it to find out the id of Project Explorer View. You will need to add a dependency to the plugin containing Project Explorer View and probably some user plugins required subsequently. Check dependencies with plugin dependencies page. To find out the id of the view you can search in jar files in the plugin directory of Eclipse Distribution for occurrences of "Project Explorer View". This way you can find plugin containing extension you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I am not able to comment on others, yet. 
Instead of searching source files, please open the Project Explorer View in your IDE and use Alt+Shift+F1 (for Buttons or menu entries it's Alt+Shift+F2) to save some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think this tutorial can help you:

http://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc/

Comment: It might be a good idea to post the relevant parts of the page here; just in case that link ever goes down.