# Eclipse RCP e4 : Add Project Explorer view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, project-explorer

I am trying to integrate a Project Explorer view into an RCP e4 application I am working on.

Unfortunately, the information I found online in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346006/how-to-add-the-project-explorer-view-to-an-eclipse-rcp-application) and [elsewhere](http://andydunkel.net/eclipse/rcp/2014/05/24/introduction_to_cnf.html) do not provide much information on how to achieve this.

It seems that e4 does not fully support the Project Explorer view (and similar other views) yet, hence the need to provide some kind of compatibility with RCP 3.x.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Grep's comments below are correct, i.e., at the moment developing a native e4 RCP is not available. Hence you need to start with an 3.x RCP and make it e4 aware.

For anyone interested the following links provide excellent answers to these issues.

- [SO - How to use Eclipse 3.x views in E4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092827/how-to-use-eclipse-3-x-views-in-e4)
- [Tutorial on developing eclipse rcp e4 with 3.x views like project explorer, properties](https://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc/)

Comment: You need to stick to the Eclipse 3.x style RCP if you want to use a workspace.

Comment: @greg-449  Thank you, Could you elaborate on this please? The links in my post say that it's possible but do not provide a way to achieve this.

Comment: Both of your links are talking about 3.x style RCPs. A pure e4 application does not support any of the resources plugins used by the Project Explorer. So you need an [3.x RCP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html) rather than an [e4 RCP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 You are right about this. Do you have any idea whether, and when, it would be possible to develop a complete e4 rcp?

Comment: If you mean including resources and old style views like the Project Explorer then I don't think any time soon (or even not so soon). The pure e4 RCP is intended for other types of app which don't use these - I have several full e4 RCPs.

Comment: @greg-449 I see. What do you suggest as a workaround for a "Project Explorer"-like view in e4 RCP?